# Xpath for selecting html id including random number

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Hi how would I select all link when they have the following id.

```
<a id="List_ctl01_link3" class="content" href=link1.aspx">
<a id="List_ctl02_link3" class="content" href=link2.aspx">
<a id="List_ctl03_link3" class="content" href=link3.aspx">
<a id="List_ctl04_link3" class="content" href=link4.aspx">
```

And so on...

Please note that the last part "link3" is important, and must be included in the Xpath.

I'm using C# and Html agility pack.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the most precise solution so far. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you use xpath 2.0 you can try [match/matches](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) functions and use regular expressions. If you are with xpath 1.0 probably you will have to write your custom attribute parser (take a look at xsl:function). AFAIR the match function is available only xpath 2.0.

Probably @id[starts-with(., 'List_ct') and ends-with(., 'link3')] is another way to do it.

Comment: Thx, I used the starts-with solution and it works perfectly :-)

Comment: Do note that there is no `fn:ends-with()` in XPath 1.0

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks. I've assumed that if there is fn:starts-with() in xpath 1.0 there should be fn:ends-with() for consistency reasons. Me bad. Had to check that.

Answer (score 5):

> Hi how would I select all **link**
>   when they have the following id

Use this XPath expression:

```
//a[@id[starts-with(.,'List_ctl')][substring(.,string-length()-5)='_link3']]
```

**Note**: There is no `fn:ends-with()` in XPath 1.0. Use last predicate instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
//a[@id[starts-with(.,'List_ctl')
      and
        substring(.,string-length()-5)='_link3'
      and
         floor(substring-before(substring_after(.,'List_ctl'),'_'))
        =
         floor(substring-before(substring_after(.,'List_ctl'),'_'))
       ]
   ]
```

**This XPath expression selects** all `a` elements in the document whose `id` attribute has string value with all of the following properties:

1. Starts with the string `'List_ctl'` .
2. Ends with the string `'_link3'` .
3. The substring surrounded by `'List_ctl'` and `'_'` is a representation of an integer.